# echo html contents with some css

Tags: php, html, css

I have been trying to echo html with some css styles in it but those css destroys my main html layout with some other css.

How am I suppose to do that without destroying my main layout

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: post us what you tryed..

Comment: Can you show us what you got?

Comment: I don't even know what echo html with some css means.

Comment: it just read some i am trying to read some html tags and store it in a variable and then echo them but these html data has some css which inturn destroys my main layout

Comment: please try to provide some answers instead of marking negation

Comment: @sujitprasad To allow us to provide answers please supply code that will allow us to reproduce the issue you are experiencing. You should also consider re-wording your question to clarify what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
echo '<style>/* styles you want */</style>';
echo '<div><!-- Your Html code --></div>';
```

Comment: this wouldn't work for <a href> tags and all links will be changed according to the  the above

Comment: You should lass or id for a tags and style that